# Python based mulitprocessing is slower than sequential approch

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a python based Mulitprocessing program to process .csv files. This program open each .csv files (around ~250 csv files) from a specific folder and add a new row in each files.

**Issue** – Time taken to process all csv files is slightly higher than normal sequential approach with multiprocessing approach. Generally multiprocessing should be faster than normal sequential process.

**result**
Multiprocess Time taken: 0:00:00.748690
Normal Time Taken: 0:00:00.253856

Do you observe anything wrong with the code or testing approach ?

## Code Snippet

```
import multiprocessing
import csv
import datetime
import os

# Process CSV - add new row to CSV - Nomral sequential way
def process_csv_normal(param):
    for p in param:
            csv_file = p.get('workspace') + "\\" + p.get('file')
            with open(csv_file, 'a') as csvfile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                writer.writerow({'AA001', 'AL', 'arunlal@email.com'})


# Main - Normal Process
def main_normal():
    # path of csv files  - Local machine folder path
    workspace = r"C:\Workdir\Python\csvfolder"
    params = [{'workspace': workspace, 'file': file_name} for file_name in os.listdir(workspace)
                  if file_name.endswith('.csv')]
    process_csv_normal(params)


# Process CSV - add new row to CSV
def process_csv_multiprocess(param):    
    csv_file = param.get('workspace') + "\\" + param.get('file')
    with open(csv_file, 'a') as csvfile:
         writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
         writer.writerow({'AA001', 'AL', 'arunlal@email.com'})


# Main - Multi process function
def main_multiprocess():

    # path of csv files  - Local machine folder path
    workspace = r"C:\Workdir\Python\csvfolder"

    # Number of files to process at a time
    process = 1

    params = [{'workspace': workspace, 'file': file_name} for file_name in os.listdir(workspace)
                  if file_name.endswith('.csv')]

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=process)
    pool.map_async(process_csv_multiprocess, params)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start=datetime.datetime.now()
    main_multiprocess()
    print("Multiprocess Time taken: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()-start))

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    main_normal()
    print("Normal Time Taken: " + str(datetime.datetime.now() - start))
```

Comment: The answer to this FAQ is nearly always, you are creating congestion by trying to parallelize stuff which is I/O bound rather than CPU bound.

Comment: Please advice which is the best way to handle this scenario as sequential will be bit slow when we need to handle 1000 files.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a file, adding a line and closing it is a very quick operation mostly bounded by disk access (i.e., it's not a CPU intensive operation). Disk access is in general not parallelizable (on HHD the head has to move to a specific position, on SSDs you need to request a certain block, etc), so multiprocessing won't help.

On top of that, you need to account for the overhead multiprocessing introduces: spawning a process pool, serializing, transferring and deserializing data, coordination, etc. All of this has a cost, which normally one balances with the benefit of having multiple *CPU-intensive* tasks running on multiple cores in parallel, which is not your case.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your view on this.  do you think any other approach to handle multiple csv's in parallel. ?

Comment: Honestly, if all you need to do with those files is adding a line, just process them sequentially. Anything else will be slower